# Is it possible to compute $\sum_{x=1}^K \binom{N}{x}$ $\text{mod }p$ in better than $O(K^2\log p)$

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, fourier-transform, fast-fourier-transform

We can compute $\binom{N}{x}$ mod ${p}$ by Fermat's little theorem in $O(x\log p)$.

So if we do same for all $x=1$ to $K$ then,

$$\sum_{x=1}^K \binom{N}{x}\text{ mod }p$$

would take $O(K^2\log p)$.

I suspect using FFT or similar techniquies we might be able to do it faster.

Note I don't need to sum till $N$, I need to sum till $K$, where $K \le N$ and $p$ is a prime.

Comment: A quick fix can save computation load by noting that binomial coefficients can be computed recursively: $$\binom{N}{0}=1, \qquad \binom{N}{i+1}=\binom{N}{i}(N-i)(i+1)^{-1}. $$ So, we only need $\mathcal{O}(K\log p)$.

Comment: @SangchulLee Let me rephrase in my own words of what I understand from your comment . do you mean $O(K \ log\ p)$ for the first  binomial coefficients, followed by O(1) for each of the remaining (K-1)  binomial coefficients ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me expand my comment. We run the following pseudocode:

> let $B = 1$;
> let $S = 0$;
> for $i$ in $\{1, \ldots, K\}$:
> $\qquad$ $B = B \cdot (N + 1 - i) \cdot i^{-1} \pmod{p}$;
> $\qquad$ $S = S + B \pmod{p}$;
> return $S$;

What the above algorithm do is to compute the following recursive formula modulo $p$:

\begin{align*}
B_0 &= {\textstyle \binom{N}{0}} = 1, &
B_i &= B_{i-1} (N+1 - i)i^{-1}, \\
S_0 &= 0, &
S_i &= S_{i-1} + B_i.
\end{align*}

Then it is easy to check that $B_i = \binom{N}{i}$ for all $i$ and $S_i = \sum_{j=1}^{i} B_j = \sum_{j=1}^{i} \binom{N}{j}$. This means that the above algorithm returns the value of $\sum_{i=1}^{K} \binom{N}{i} \pmod{p}$.

Moreover, each step in the loop takes $\mathcal{O}(\log p)$, with the most expensive one being the computation of $i^{-1}$ modulo $p$. Hence, the entire loop takes $\mathcal{O}(K\log p)$.

Comment: I see. Now I get it. I had mistaken $i^{−1}\  modulo\ p$ to be O(1)